# heroku.com page can't be found - app is rails api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, heroku

I have a rails api with react client. my rails api works fine locally. 
When i pushed it to heroku it deployed but when went to view it said my page couldn't be found. 
i added a root route which is what it was asking for(?) but to no avail... any help would be appreciated! 
i also tested heroku by deploying test rails apps. 
If they were made with --api, the page once again couldn't be found.
I made one without --api, it worked initially but when tried to migrate db it resulted in debug #4 errors...

```
                               Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
                         api_v1_users GET    /api/v1/users(.:format)                                                                  api/v1/users#index
                                      POST   /api/v1/users(.:format)                                                                  api/v1/users#create
                          api_v1_user GET    /api/v1/users/:id(.:format)                                                              api/v1/users#show
                                      PATCH  /api/v1/users/:id(.:format)                                                              api/v1/users#update
                                      PUT    /api/v1/users/:id(.:format)                                                              api/v1/users#update
                                      DELETE /api/v1/users/:id(.:format)                                                              api/v1/users#destroy
                          api_v1_pets GET    /api/v1/pets(.:format)                                                                   api/v1/pets#index
                                      POST   /api/v1/pets(.:format)                                                                   api/v1/pets#create
                           api_v1_pet GET    /api/v1/pets/:id(.:format)                                                               api/v1/pets#show
                                      PATCH  /api/v1/pets/:id(.:format)                                                               api/v1/pets#update
                                      PUT    /api/v1/pets/:id(.:format)                                                               api/v1/pets#update
                                      DELETE /api/v1/pets/:id(.:format)                                                               api/v1/pets#destroy
                               api_v1 PATCH  /api/v1/pets/:id/toggle_adopt(.:format)                                                  api/v1/pets#toggle_adopt
                                      POST   /api/v1/pets/:id/adopt(.:format)                                                         api/v1/pets#adopt
                                      POST   /api/v1/users/:id/get_pet(.:format)                                                      api/v1/users#get_pet
                                      GET    /api/v1(.:format)                                                                        api/v1/pets#index
                         api_v1_login POST   /api/v1/login(.:format)                                                                  api/v1/auth#login
                    api_v1_auto_login GET    /api/v1/auto_login(.:format)                                                             api/v1/auth#auto_login
        rails_mandrill_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/mandrill/inbound_emails(.:format)                                  action_mailbox/ingresses/mandrill/inbound_emails#create
        rails_postmark_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/postmark/inbound_emails(.:format)                                  action_mailbox/ingresses/postmark/inbound_emails#create
           rails_relay_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/relay/inbound_emails(.:format)                                     action_mailbox/ingresses/relay/inbound_emails#create
        rails_sendgrid_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/sendgrid/inbound_emails(.:format)                                  action_mailbox/ingresses/sendgrid/inbound_emails#create
         rails_mailgun_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/mailgun/inbound_emails/mime(.:format)                              action_mailbox/ingresses/mailgun/inbound_emails#create
       rails_conductor_inbound_emails GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails(.:format)                                 rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#index
                                      POST   /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails(.:format)                                 rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#create
        rails_conductor_inbound_email GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#show
                                      PATCH  /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#update
                                      PUT    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#update
                                      DELETE /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#destroy
rails_conductor_inbound_email_reroute POST   /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/:inbound_email_id/reroute(.:format)                      rails/conductor/action_mailbox/reroutes#create
                   rails_service_blob GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                               active_storage/blobs#show
            rails_blob_representation GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format) active_storage/representations#show
                   rails_disk_service GET    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_key/*filename(.:format)                              active_storage/disk#show
            update_rails_disk_service PUT    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_token(.:format)                                      active_storage/disk#update
                 rails_direct_uploads POST   /rails/active_storage/direct_uploads(.:format)                                           active_storage/direct_uploads#create
```

````
// ♥ heroku logs
2020-02-19T16:44:53.897044+00:00 app[web.1]: [0e32db7c-e3cb-4afb-a003-d73b769ce813] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
2020-02-19T16:44:53.897044+00:00 app[web.1]: [0e32db7c-e3cb-4afb-a003-d73b769ce813] railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2020-02-19T16:44:53.897044+00:00 app[web.1]: [0e32db7c-e3cb-4afb-a003-d73b769ce813] railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
2020-02-19T16:44:53.897044+00:00 app[web.1]: [0e32db7c-e3cb-4afb-a003-d73b769ce813] activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'
2020-02-19T16:44:53.897045+00:00 app[web.1]: [0e32db7c-e3cb-4afb-a003-d73b769ce813] activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
2020-02-19T16:44:53.897045+00:00 app[web.1]: [0e32db7c-e3cb-4afb-a003-d73b769ce813] activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'
2020-02-19T16:44:53.897045+00:00 app[web.1]: [0e32db7c-e3cb-4afb-a003-d73b769ce813] railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
2020-02-19T16:44:53.897046+00:00 app[web.1]: [0e32db7c-e3cb-4afb-a003-d73b769ce813] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
2020-02-19T16:44:53.897046+00:00 app[web.1]: [0e32db7c-e3cb-4afb-a003-d73b769ce813] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
2020-02-19T16:44:53.897046+00:00 app[web.1]: [0e32db7c-e3cb-4afb-a003-d73b769ce813] rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2020-02-19T16:44:53.897047+00:00 app[web.1]: [0e32db7c-e3cb-4afb-a003-d73b769ce813] activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
2020-02-19T16:44:53.897047+00:00 app[web.1]: [0e32db7c-e3cb-4afb-a003-d73b769ce813] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
2020-02-19T16:44:53.897047+00:00 app[web.1]: [0e32db7c-e3cb-4afb-a003-d73b769ce813] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in `call'
2020-02-19T16:44:53.897047+00:00 app[web.1]: [0e32db7c-e3cb-4afb-a003-d73b769ce813] rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
2020-02-19T16:44:53.897047+00:00 app[web.1]: [0e32db7c-e3cb-4afb-a003-d73b769ce813] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:77:in `call'
2020-02-19T16:44:53.897048+00:00 app[web.1]: [0e32db7c-e3cb-4afb-a003-d73b769ce813] rack-cors (1.1.1) lib/rack/cors.rb:100:in `call'
2020-02-19T16:44:53.897048+00:00 app[web.1]: [0e32db7c-e3cb-4afb-a003-d73b769ce813] railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:526:in `call'
2020-02-19T16:44:53.897048+00:00 app[web.1]: [0e32db7c-e3cb-4afb-a003-d73b769ce813] puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
2020-02-19T16:44:53.897048+00:00 app[web.1]: [0e32db7c-e3cb-4afb-a003-d73b769ce813] puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:681:in `handle_request'
2020-02-19T16:44:53.897049+00:00 app[web.1]: [0e32db7c-e3cb-4afb-a003-d73b769ce813] puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
2020-02-19T16:44:53.897049+00:00 app[web.1]: [0e32db7c-e3cb-4afb-a003-d73b769ce813] puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
2020-02-19T16:44:53.897049+00:00 app[web.1]: [0e32db7c-e3cb-4afb-a003-d73b769ce813] puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'
2020-02-19T17:22:24.570026+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2020-02-19T17:22:24.573775+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2020-02-19T17:22:25.738188+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-02-19T17:22:25.771134+00:00 app[web.1]: - Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
2020-02-19T17:22:25.773522+00:00 app[web.1]: === puma shutdown: 2020-02-19 17:22:25 +0000 ===
2020-02-19T17:22:25.773546+00:00 app[web.1]: - Goodbye!
2020-02-19T17:22:25.866786+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2020-02-19T18:47:00.519301+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2020-02-19T18:47:00.536382+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2020-02-19T18:47:03.058431+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-development}`
2020-02-19T18:47:05.399248+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2020-02-19T18:47:05.399262+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 4.3.1 (ruby 2.6.5-p114), codename: Mysterious Traveller
2020-02-19T18:47:05.399263+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2020-02-19T18:47:05.399263+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2020-02-19T18:47:11.357442+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:54444
2020-02-19T18:47:11.357812+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2020-02-19T18:47:11.926899+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-02-19T18:47:12.591966+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=OPTIONS path="/api/v1/auto_login" host=boiling-garden-61294.herokuapp.com request_id=63546cfe-0db6-4273-88ff-652097e7432c fwd="184.153.22.244" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=307 protocol=https
2020-02-19T19:02:50.855756+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-02-19T19:02:50.855651 #4]  INFO -- : [3c337a3b-162b-4362-8d16-0ed2f50318c5] Started GET "/api/v1/auto_login" for 184.153.22.244 at 2020-02-19 19:02:50 +0000
2020-02-19T19:02:50.857404+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-02-19T19:02:50.857329 #4]  INFO -- : [3c337a3b-162b-4362-8d16-0ed2f50318c5] Processing by Api::V1::AuthController#auto_login as */*
2020-02-19T19:02:52.341221+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2020-02-19T19:02:52.341059 #4] DEBUG -- : [3c337a3b-162b-4362-8d16-0ed2f50318c5]   User Load (17.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2020-02-19T19:02:52.426916+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2020-02-19T19:02:52.426791 #4] DEBUG -- : [3c337a3b-162b-4362-8d16-0ed2f50318c5]   CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2020-02-19T19:02:52.473014+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2020-02-19T19:02:52.472882 #4] DEBUG -- : [3c337a3b-162b-4362-8d16-0ed2f50318c5] [active_model_serializers]   Pet Load (35.6ms)  SELECT "pets".* FROM "pets" WHERE "pets"."owner_id" = $1  [["owner_id", 4]]
2020-02-19T19:02:52.493448+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-02-19T19:02:52.493334 #4]  INFO -- : [3c337a3b-162b-4362-8d16-0ed2f50318c5] [active_model_serializers] Rendered UserSerializer with ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::Attributes (65.55ms)
2020-02-19T19:02:52.493828+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-02-19T19:02:52.493752 #4]  INFO -- : [3c337a3b-162b-4362-8d16-0ed2f50318c5] Completed 200 OK in 1636ms (Views: 23.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1558.9ms | Allocations: 17956)
2020-02-19T19:02:52.495894+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/v1/auto_login" host=boiling-garden-61294.herokuapp.com request_id=3c337a3b-162b-4362-8d16-0ed2f50318c5 fwd="184.153.22.244" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1641ms status=304 bytes=636 protocol=https
2020-02-19T19:38:32.700667+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2020-02-19T19:38:32.705096+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2020-02-19T19:38:33.831696+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-02-19T19:38:33.852410+00:00 app[web.1]: - Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
2020-02-19T19:38:33.858074+00:00 app[web.1]: === puma shutdown: 2020-02-19 19:38:33 +0000 ===
2020-02-19T19:38:33.858355+00:00 app[web.1]: - Goodbye!
2020-02-19T19:38:33.969920+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2020-02-19T20:07:07.613633+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2020-02-19T20:07:07.628601+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2020-02-19T20:07:10.629524+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-development}`
2020-02-19T20:07:13.443149+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2020-02-19T20:07:13.443242+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 4.3.1 (ruby 2.6.5-p114), codename: Mysterious Traveller
2020-02-19T20:07:13.443243+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2020-02-19T20:07:13.443244+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2020-02-19T20:07:19.064575+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:26954
2020-02-19T20:07:19.065126+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2020-02-19T20:07:19.389039+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-02-19T20:07:21.691904+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-02-19T20:07:21.691780 #4]  INFO -- : [de344029-a862-437f-8eeb-e7c3092c3894] Started GET "/" for 184.153.22.244 at 2020-02-19 20:07:21 +0000
2020-02-19T20:07:21.693363+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-02-19T20:07:21.693281 #4] FATAL -- : [de344029-a862-437f-8eeb-e7c3092c3894]
2020-02-19T20:07:21.693364+00:00 app[web.1]: [de344029-a862-437f-8eeb-e7c3092c3894] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
2020-02-19T20:07:21.693365+00:00 app[web.1]: [de344029-a862-437f-8eeb-e7c3092c3894]
2020-02-19T20:07:21.693379+00:00 app[web.1]: [de344029-a862-437f-8eeb-e7c3092c3894] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:36:in `call'
2020-02-19T20:07:21.693379+00:00 app[web.1]: [de344029-a862-437f-8eeb-e7c3092c3894] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
2020-02-19T20:07:21.693380+00:00 app[web.1]: [de344029-a862-437f-8eeb-e7c3092c3894] railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2020-02-19T20:07:21.693380+00:00 app[web.1]: [de344029-a862-437f-8eeb-e7c3092c3894] railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
2020-02-19T20:07:21.693381+00:00 app[web.1]: [de344029-a862-437f-8eeb-e7c3092c3894] activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'
2020-02-19T20:07:21.693381+00:00 app[web.1]: [de344029-a862-437f-8eeb-e7c3092c3894] activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
2020-02-19T20:07:21.693381+00:00 app[web.1]: [de344029-a862-437f-8eeb-e7c3092c3894] activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'
2020-02-19T20:07:21.693382+00:00 app[web.1]: [de344029-a862-437f-8eeb-e7c3092c3894] railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
2020-02-19T20:07:21.693382+00:00 app[web.1]: [de344029-a862-437f-8eeb-e7c3092c3894] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
2020-02-19T20:07:21.693382+00:00 app[web.1]: [de344029-a862-437f-8eeb-e7c3092c3894] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
2020-02-19T20:07:21.693383+00:00 app[web.1]: [de344029-a862-437f-8eeb-e7c3092c3894] rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2020-02-19T20:07:21.693384+00:00 app[web.1]: [de344029-a862-437f-8eeb-e7c3092c3894] activesupport (6.0.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
2020-02-19T20:07:21.693385+00:00 app[web.1]: [de344029-a862-437f-8eeb-e7c3092c3894] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
2020-02-19T20:07:21.693385+00:00 app[web.1]: [de344029-a862-437f-8eeb-e7c3092c3894] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in `call'
2020-02-19T20:07:21.693385+00:00 app[web.1]: [de344029-a862-437f-8eeb-e7c3092c3894] rack (2.2.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
2020-02-19T20:07:21.693386+00:00 app[web.1]: [de344029-a862-437f-8eeb-e7c3092c3894] actionpack (6.0.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:77:in `call'
2020-02-19T20:07:21.693386+00:00 app[web.1]: [de344029-a862-437f-8eeb-e7c3092c3894] rack-cors (1.1.1) lib/rack/cors.rb:100:in `call'
2020-02-19T20:07:21.693387+00:00 app[web.1]: [de344029-a862-437f-8eeb-e7c3092c3894] railties (6.0.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:526:in `call'
2020-02-19T20:07:21.693387+00:00 app[web.1]: [de344029-a862-437f-8eeb-e7c3092c3894] puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
2020-02-19T20:07:21.693387+00:00 app[web.1]: [de344029-a862-437f-8eeb-e7c3092c3894] puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:681:in `handle_request'
2020-02-19T20:07:21.693388+00:00 app[web.1]: [de344029-a862-437f-8eeb-e7c3092c3894] puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
2020-02-19T20:07:21.693388+00:00 app[web.1]: [de344029-a862-437f-8eeb-e7c3092c3894] puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
2020-02-19T20:07:21.693389+00:00 app[web.1]: [de344029-a862-437f-8eeb-e7c3092c3894] puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'
2020-02-19T20:07:21.695902+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=boiling-garden-61294.herokuapp.com request_id=de344029-a862-437f-8eeb-e7c3092c3894 fwd="184.153.22.244" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=404 bytes=191 protocol=https
2020-02-19T20:38:22.500446+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2020-02-19T20:38:22.505029+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2020-02-19T20:38:23.149591+00:00 app[web.1]: - Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
2020-02-19T20:38:23.150452+00:00 app[web.1]: === puma shutdown: 2020-02-19 20:38:23 +0000 ===
2020-02-19T20:38:23.150454+00:00 app[web.1]: - Goodbye!
2020-02-19T20:38:23.141795+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-02-19T20:38:23.197413+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143```
````

Comment: It sounds like you don't have a root route, can you post your routes.rb

Comment: i added the routes, though i didn't think i needed a root route when the app is an api(?) - i just added it to appease heroku...

Comment: Well there is no root route in the routes that you posted though.  It would be at the `/` url, which there isn't one.  It does look like you can go to other URLS like `https://boiling-garden-61294.herokuapp.com/api/v1`   But it won't just load a root page if there isn't one set.  So is the issue you are having that when you go to the root page `https://boiling-garden-61294.herokuapp.com/` you don;t see anything?  It sounds like you don't need to.  It does look like the routes are working, at least for some, others look broken which is an issue with code most likely and not Heroku it seems.

Comment: thanks for the response! 
basically the root page https://boiling-garden-61294.herokuapp.com says url (page) can't be found...
btw i tried both:  root :to => "pets#index" and  get "/", to: "pets#index" - neither worked.

Comment: But you said you don't need a root route, didn't you?  The pages load at other URLS, I'm not sure what exactly the issue you are having is, do you need a root page to display?  Is your question about how to set that up?  In your rake routes output you don't have any `pets` routes, where is that coming from?  Is there a pets controller with views?

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal behavior in `--api` only applications, simply rails doesn't know what to serve. In API only applications `ApplicationController` inherits from `ActionController::API` instead of `ActionController::Base` which removes some functionality required by browsers.

> An API Controller is different from a normal controller in the sense that by default it doesn't include some features that are usually required by browser access only: layouts and templates rendering, flash, assets, and so on. This makes the entire controller stack thinner, suitable for API applications. It doesn't mean you won't have such features if you need them: they're all available for you to include in your application, they're just not part of the default API controller stack.

Source: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/API.html

If you have designed the application as json api, all json format urls should work fine.

Comment: thanks for your reply! the problem i'm having is that when i refresh the client side, it breaks - netlify (client side) says ' page not found. looks like you've followed a broken link or entered a url that doesn't exist on this site.' ;(